# How to answer this complex XPath query

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

suppose we have the following XML document:

```
<visits>
<folder>
    <consultation date="2015-07-01" doctor="d4"> ... </consultation>
    <consultation date="2016-05-02" doctor="d1"> ... </consultation>
    <consultation date="2020-01-01" doctor="d3"> ... </consultation>
    <consultation date="2021-12-02" doctor="d2"> ... </consultation>
    <patient id="p2">
        <name>aaaa</name>
        <phone>..</phone>
    </patient>
</folder>
<folder>
    <consultation date="2017-01-01" doctor="d2"> ... </consultation>
    <consultation date="2019-01-01" doctor="d4"> ... </consultation>
    <patient id="p1">
        <name>bbbbb</name>
        <phone>...</phone>
    </patient>
</folder>
<doctor id="d1">
    <speciality>gynecologist</speciality>
</doctor>
<doctor id="d2">
    <speciality>cardiologist</speciality>
</doctor>
<doctor id="d3">
    <speciality>gynecologist</speciality>
</doctor>
<doctor id="d4">
    <speciality>cardiologist</speciality>
</doctor>
```

in XPath 1.0, I want to get the patients who have seen doctors of all specialties.

Here is my attempt:

```
    //patient[count (../consultation[????]) =
    count(//doctor[not (speciality = preceding-sibling::doctor/speciality)])]
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any XPath-1.0 solution, but if you can use XPath-2.0, the following path does work:

```
/visits/folder[patient[every $x in /visits/doctor/@id satisfies $x=../consultation/@doctor]]
```

This expression selects all `<folder>` elements that match the required condition.